# Mysql users can select from tables but not views

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have a mysql database on which I create users, and grant them select, update, insert and delete on a particular database.

The database contains both tables and views. For some reason these created users get the following error when trying to select from a view.

```
Access denied for user 'someuser'@'%' (using password: YES)

SELECT * FROM (`someview`) WHERE `somecolumn` = 0
```

I don't however get this error when selecting from a table in the same database.

I have deployed this application to multiple places and it's working everywhere else including using amazon rds. this particular instance is a mysql server running on amazon ec2.

Comment: what if you explicitly grant select on the view to the user?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Solved it. The error message is misleading.

The cause was the user who was the definer of the views no longer existed, not the user who was selecting from the view.

I re-created this user and all is well.

Comment: I had to recreate the user and also grant it access to the tables used in the view.

Comment: Another solution may be to change views DDL from `CREATE ... DEFINER = 'root'@'%'' SQL SECURITY DEFINER` to `SECURITY INVOKER`

Comment: @allofmex And how would one go about that?

Comment: In my case, view defined is `some_user`@`%`, after recreating the users based on host such as `some_user`@`10.10.10.5`, I'm getting the similar error: access denied for user `some_user`@`10.10.10.5`.
what can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

There are possible reasons why you encountered this:

- It may be the user you have used to access this does not have enough privilege on this particular table.
- It may be the username or password doesn't match.
- It may be the user doesn't exist for the specified host.